# Error getting a downloaded file path with path_provider to video_player

Tags: dart, flutter

My app will download videos, in first screen will be possible to download the videos, I am using dio and getting the app folder with path_provider, in the second screen I want show and play the downloaded video.

The download is ok, is being stored in the right path but I can't retrieve the same path to video_player, I'm getting "file not found".

path the file was downloaded: /data/user/0/APP_NAME/app_flutter/ATW - Around the World.mp4

path the error show: flutter_assets//data/user/0/APP_NAME/app_flutter/ATW - Around the World.mp4

Looks like they are not the same.

```
Dio dio = Dio();

      try {

        var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

        for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){

          path = "${dir.path}/${tricks[i]}.mp4";

          await dio.download(urls[i], path, onReceiveProgress: (rec, total){

            setState(() {

              progress = ((rec / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";

            });

          });

          print(path);

        }


      } catch (e){
        print(e);
      }

===============


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  String trickName;


  VideoScreen(this.trickName);

  @override
  _VideoScreenState createState() => _VideoScreenState(trickName);
}

class _VideoScreenState extends State<VideoScreen> {

  String trickName;
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  dynamic videoPath;

  _VideoScreenState(this.trickName);

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    _getVideoPath();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Trick"),
         centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getVideoPath(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
            return Center(
              child: _controller.value.initialized ? AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              )
              : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
            }

          }
      ),


    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _getVideoPath() async{

    try{

      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      videoPath = "${dir.path}/$trickName.mp4";

      print(videoPath);


      _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(videoPath)..initialize()
          .then((_){
        setState(() {

        });
      });

    }catch (e){
      print(e);
    }

  }


}
```

> I/ExoPlayerImpl(20059): Init 5dd991d [ExoPlayerLib/2.9.6] [m253,
>   LG-K430, LGE, 23]
>       I/ExoPlayerImpl(20059): Init 8355563 [ExoPlayerLib/2.9.6] [m253, LG-K430, LGE, 23]
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059): Source error.
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059): com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource$AssetDataSourceException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   flutter_assets//data/user/0/APP_NAME/app_flutter/ATW - Around the
>   World.mp4
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource.open(AssetDataSource.java:98)
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:250)
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:885)
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:381)
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   flutter_assets//data/user/0/APP_NAME/app_flutter/ATW - Around the
>   World.mp4
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource.open(AssetDataSource.java:79)
>       E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20059):   ... 7 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

video_player have a function for files: VideoPlayerController.file(File)

My Android Studio was not showing the function so I thought that it wasn't implemented.

Now I can load videos from the app folder.